# Copy Windows files to SMB share (Synology) and keep all properties

Tags: windows, server-message-block, file-transfer, synology

I have a network drive with files that need to move to a new Synology NAS SMB network share. I'd like to transfer the files while keeping as much properties as possible.

I tried robocopy and fastcopy, but these tools don't do the trick. The permissions (in a domain) are altered based on the settings in the Synology share settings and the owner is changed to my admin account.

Can I prevent that modification?

Comment: Long story short, this is always an issue with Linux based NAS systems because the underlying file system doesn’t understand Windows ACLs. But have you seen this? https://originwww.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_migrate_ACL_permissions_to_Synology_NAS

Comment: @Appleoddity I didn't find that KB article no, but it's helpful. Somehow the owner details are copied over correctly to the new location now. That's what I needed the most

Answer (score 1):

Linux (based) fileservers do not have a filesystem with [ACLs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List) like windows does (with NTFS or ReFS). You simply can not keep all your NTFS-Settings like ACLs, Junctions, Filestreams or extended attributes on a non-NTFS filesystem.

Most Linux FS expose the [POSIX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Operating_System_Interface) attributes (OWNER, GROUP, RIGHTS). If you have more than one group entry, you'd have to greate one group for each and every ACL-Kombination.

But you *can* export your NFTS ACLs. Use this command to backup you NTFS permissions:

```
icacls d:data /save NTFS-acls.txt /t /c
```

The /T switch allows it to get subfolder permissions too. The /C switch allows it to continue even if errors are encountered. Errors will still be displayed.

Use this command to restore them:

```
icacls d: /restore NTFS-acls.txt
```

Note that in the command to save the permissions there is no slash. [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/11/24/how-to-back-up-and-restore-ntfs-and-share-permissions/) you can read why this is important.